# Getting "Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3" when trying to use Visualizer with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-permissions, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, visualizer

I am using ExoPlayer to play audio from a URL. I need to use a visualizer and picked the following library to do that: https://github.com/gauravk95/audio-visualizer-android

Problem is, when I use it with ExoPlayer (and not MediaPlayer), I am getting the following error even after making sure the permissions are in place:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:218)
    at com.example.visualizer.BaseVisualizer.setAudioSessionId(BaseVisualizer.java:196)
```

and this is while trying to create a new instance of Visualizer in BaseVisualizer:

```
        mVisualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionId);
```

The audio session Id is passed to BaseVisualizer from SimpleExoPlayer instance created to play the media. When I checked the logs, the session id is 0.

On the permissions front, I have added both RECORD_AUDIO and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS in manifest and checking for RECORD_AUDIO permission in run time if not given already. Permissions are getting granted correctly and I have verified the same in the app.

What could be going wrong here? Any ideas?

Thanks,

AB